# Salesforce error with certificate issue

Tags: java, ssl, certificates

In our application we are using two way ssl that to send the data in soap api with request and response. it is the communication between salesforce and java. java is server and salesforce is client. in server they created a ssl configuration with whitelist authority signature.
In salesforce we created a certificate(self signed certificate) and converted to jks to p12 format and kept in java server.

without client certificate configuration it is working fine(that means with only server certficate it is working fine.)but when we do this client certificate,now we are getting this following error.

```
retrying request in response to handshake failure: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Please suggest something.

Is there any issue with salesforce side?

Comment: Did you look at http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/77446/apex-callout-failed-due-to-suncertpathbuilderexception

Comment: @GauravKheterpal ours certificate also self signed certificate but the comment of the answer also tells that self signed certificates are ok.  I am not sure exactly that whether there is any problem of understanding this entire certificate scenarios.